# Qt5. QMacNativeWidget. Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: cocoa, qt

Class **QMacNativeWidget** listed in Qt5 documentation, but any attempts to create Cocoa application with embedded Qt Widgets give me the next error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "QMacNativeWidget::QMacNativeWidget(void*)", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate loadUi] in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is my code:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    std::auto_ptr<QWidget> nativeWidget;
    ...
}
// Qt Widget will be attached to this view
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSView *view; 
@end

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [self initQtIfNeeded];
    [self loadUi];
}

-(void) initQtIfNeeded
{
    QApplication* app = qApp;
    if (app == 0)
    {
        puts("Creating new QApplication instance...");
        QApplication::setDesktopSettingsAware(true);
        QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_MacPluginApplication, true);
        int argc = 0;
        app = new QApplication(argc, NULL);
        ...
    }
}

-(void)loadUi
{
    nativeWidget.reset(new QMacNativeWidget());
    ...

    // Casting pointer (x86_64 with ARC)
    void* winId = reinterpret_cast<void *>(nativeWidget->winId());
    NSView *nativeWidgetNSView = (__bridge NSView*)winId;

    // Attaching Qt Widget to NSView
    [self.view addSubview:nativeWidgetNSView positioned:NSWindowAbove relativeTo:nil];
    nativeWidget->setGeometry(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    ...

    nativeWidget->show();
}
```

When i am using QWidget instead of QMacNativeWidget (i.e.: `nativeWidget.reset(new QWidget());`) application get linked successfully but at runtime additional window created .(

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUySd.png)

**My question:** Am i doing something wrong or it is Qt issue?
Thanks!

Comment: What libraries are you linking against?

Comment: Using this set of libraries: `-lQt5Gui_debug -lQt5Core_debug  -lQt5PlatformSupport_debug  -lQt5PrintSupport_debug  -lQt5Widgets_debug`

Comment: Just receive e-mail from Digia. They told me that `QMacNativeWidget` is now part of separate package [QtMacExtras](http://qt.gitorious.org/qtplayground/qtmacextras). This package will be part of Qt later (planned for Qt 5.1). Documentation for `QMacNativeWidget` in Qt5 was generated by mistake and they deal with it later.

Comment: QtMacExtras repository seems moved to new location: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtmacextras

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I solved the problem changing the file extension from ".cpp" to ".mm". I see this trick in some QtBug description, tried and works for me (using statically builded Qt 5.7). The .mm extension is used in Objective-C++ code, a mix of Objective-C and C++. Using the .cpp extension I have the "Undefined Symbols" error.